# Deleted method is still executed even though it's not existing anymore Vue.js

Tags: laravel-5, methods, vue.js

Has anybody here experienced deleting a method in vue.js but is still triggered or executed during run-time? I have a button before and assigned a method to trigger or execute:

```
<div>
     <ui-button raised @click="search()">Search</ui-button>
</div>

methods:{
    search(){
        //search this and that
    }
}
```

But in the long run of our development, we deleted the method and replace it with a new one.

```
<div>
     <ui-button raised @click="dothisInstead()">Search</ui-button>
</div>

methods:{
    dothisInstead(){
        //search this and that
    }
}
```

And that works very well. But just this day, if we click the search button, it's looking for the `search()` method and executing its lines even though it's non-existent and now it throws error.

I have tried clearing my cache, restarting my PC, restarting my compiler and XAMPP and nothing has changed. Then I also tried `composer dump-autoload` and works. And just this moment, the error came back and `dump-autoload` is not fixing it. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: This might be a stupid question... But are you using webpack or any other bundlers? If so, are you sure you have built the files after the changes?

Comment: @SølveTornøe Yes I have built the files after the changes.

Comment: Have you tried to [Empty cache and hard reload](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/empty-cache-hard-reload-chrome)

Comment: @SølveTornøe Yes. And the problem here is my troubleshooting used sometimes worked and sometimes not.